# how to join split char to a escaped char

Tags: java

I hava a question about how to help join split char to a escaped char?
there is a example
**what i want is to join divide char to a escaped char**
**the escape rule should follow the java escape rule**
**Example Input**
char[] input = {'\', 'n', '\', 't', 'w', 'n'};
**Expect Output**
char[] expectOutput = {'\n', '\t', 'w', 'n'};

```java
public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] input = {'\\', 'n', '\\', 't', 'w', 'n'};
    char[] expect = {'\n', '\t', 'w', 'n'};
    char[] output = simpleImpl(input);
  }

  private static char[] simpleImpl(char[] input) {
    char[] output = new char[input.length];
    char prev = '\0';
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      char ch = input[i];
      if (ch == '\\') {
        prev = ch;
      }
      //need to escape
      else if (prev == '\\') {
        if (ch == 'n') {
          output[index++] = '\n';
        } else if (ch == 't') {
          output[index++] = '\t';
        } else {
          // there are too many case
        }
      }
      //simple char
      else {
        output[index++] = ch;
      }
    }
    return output;
  }
}
```

there are too many cases i can not full coverage

maybe some library can implement this or some better implement

Comment: Try providing a `Map<Character, Character>` which contains the unescaped character as the key and the escaped version as the value, e.g. you fill it via `escapedMap.put('n','\n')`, `escapedMap.put('t','\t')` etc. Then you just need to lookup the escaped version, e.g. `escapedMap.get(ch)`. If you don't get anything you've encountered an illegal escape sequence. Btw, there aren't really that many escape sequences, at least [not in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).